# printf prints a weird character after malloc

Tags: c

I'm trying to append on a string. So I'm starting with `malloc` and I append on that string.

```
char * loc,*X,*Y;
X = "4";
Y = "8";
loc = (char *)malloc(strlen(X)+strlen(Y)+6); //its +1 for the comma between, +1 for '\0' and +2 for "->" +2 for "()".
strcat(loc,"->");
strcat(loc,"(");
strcat(loc,X);
strcat(loc,",");
strcat(loc,Y);
strcat(loc,")");
printf("%s\n", loc);
```

So when I run it I'm waiting to see:

> ->(4,8)

Instead there is a weird character in the beginning of the string and I see this:

> └->(4,8)

If I clean the string after `malloc` with `strcpy(loc,"")` it's not there.
Why does this

> └

appear in the first place??

Comment: Initialize your string after malloc, for example by `loc[0] = 0;`

Comment: Where does one start? Casting malloc is bad - google that

Comment: Perhaps `snprintf` would be better

Comment: Note that using `malloc(strlen(X)+strlen(Y)+sizeof("->(,)"))` documents concisely what the `6` is for — `sizeof()` counts the null byte, unlike `strlen()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) function doesn't initialize the memory it allocates. Its contents is *indeterminate*. And as such, you don't know where, or even *if* there is a string terminator in that memory.

The `strcpy` function doesn't care about the existing contents, and will write a terminator. The `strcat` function on the other hand relies on finding a string terminator to know where it should start writing, but as we already established there might not even be a terminator in the memory.

So you have four choices:

1. Use [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) as the first call, instead of [`strcat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat).
2. Explicitly set the first element to a terminator, as in `loc[0] = '\0'`
3. Use [`calloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) which initializes the memory to zero, which just happens to be the same as the string terminator.
4. Use [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) instead.

I recommend choice four.

Answer (score 2):

As it is now, your code accesses uninitialized memory, invoking undefined behavior. There could be *anything* in that buffer.

You need to initialize the memory. Since you're treating the bugger as a C string, it will suffice to simply set the first byte to the NUL terminator, `\0`.

```
*loc = '\0';
```

Now you have a valid string of length zero.